# Macro for creating Tables with Names

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that currently creates tables, however the user will be creating many over and over in this document.  The document will be locked so the user wont be able to add or delete rows if needed so I plan to make a macro that will unlock, let them add or delete rows, then lock again.

The issue is I believe the user would need to know the name of the table and that will be hard when they are on Table154.

I would like macro to start with an input box allowing them to name the Table prior to table generation.  This way when they use the macro later on to add or delete rows they can reference the name they gave the table.

Comment: You can rename the table after it's created by setting its [`.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.name).

Comment: I am looking to avoid renaming a table and just have it created with the correct name

Comment: [`ListObjects.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobjects.add) doesn't allow you to specify the name in advance. You have to rename. However, this can be done immediately after creating the table. Get the desired name prior to creating the table, and immediately rename the table after creating it. The end user won't know the difference.

Comment: You do have to validate whether the user input is a valid table name though.

Answer (score 0):

- Users might forget the table name, especially if there are numerous tables in the workbook, even if your code creates a table with a customized name based on the user's input.

How about the walkaround solution (eg. for insert rows)

- Users should select a cell within the table before clicking the button. This way, users don't need to worry about the table name.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With ActiveCell
        Dim oTab As ListObject
        Set oTab = .ListObject
        If oTab Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Please select a cell within the table.", vbCritical
        Else
            Dim iCnt, i As Long
            iCnt = InputBox("How many rows added to the table:")
            If IsNumeric(iCnt) And Val(iCnt) > 0 Then
                ActiveSheet.Unprotect
                For i = 1 To Val(iCnt)
                    oTab.ListRows.Add
                Next
                ActiveSheet.Protect
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]